# C++ - print error message if account number not found

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers

So I'm creating a program that will implement various classes which represent a bank, its customers and its bank accounts. The Bank object stores a collection of Customer objects, as well as a collection of Account objects. Each Customer will have their own separate collection of the accounts that belong to them.

Below is a picture of what the program should output - in the event where a user is trying to input a negative amount or if they try to withdraw more funds than they have in their account, an error message gets printed out saying the account number cannot be debited or credited by this amount. My program outputs this portion correctly, however I'm struggling to figure out how to output an error message when the account number is not found like in the picture.

So for example, in the main I have two functions:

```
void initBank(Bank& b){
  b.addCust(new Customer(1010, "Toby"));
  b.addAcct(1010, new Account(200130, 400.4f));
}
void transactions(Bank& b)
{
  b.debit(200130, 20.00f);
  b.debit(200174, 85.00f);
}
```

While 200130 matches Toby's account, the number 200174 does not match anyone's account so it would print out the error "200174 cannot be found." I'm struggling with achieving this as I'm not quite sure how to check if an account number with an amount to be debited/credited does not match any account number of an existing customer. I would appreciate any help or hints in the right direction.

The debit and credit functions in Account.cc is the location that prints out these messages while Bank.cc also calls these functions.

Would also appreciate if people could refrain from posting larges amounts of my code and only post the lines necessary in the answers section as I'm still working on this project and am waiting until I actually finish it to publish it :)

Bank.cc: https://zerobin.net/?c39a2d26c993a4f3#GuMG6bVh53CogRqqR8of9y5YVosGIroURBrCUQFEkI8=

Customer.cc: https://pastebin.com/C40q3ehp

CustArray.cc: https://pastebin.com/6QYFDeHD

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are printing the errors, where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is I'm only printing what is in the red line I drew in the image. I would like to print the 'Account number not found' messages but I'm not quite sure how. The image is what my output should look like but right now it only prints the 4 lines I marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do it by altering your credit() and debit() functions, all you need is check if the control got out of your for loop(line 51 in back.cc `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBankAccounts; ++i)`) or not with the required value.
you can simply do it by creating/initialising a boolean value in the beginning and change it when you find a matching bank account.

something like this :-

```cpp
bool flag = false;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBankAccounts; ++i){
        if(accountsBank[i]->getNumber() == acctNum){
            flag = true;
            accountsBank[i]->debit(amount);
            break;
        }
if(!flag){
    // if the control reaches here this means the account number does not exist thus display an error message
}
```

you can also do it by returning the error code just like @Tanveer Badar said.

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple of things here, which you may already have in your program but not made them apparent in the question.

1. You must have a collection of accounts somewhere, indexed by account ID/key. Think of it like a `std::map<int, Account> accounts`.
2. When you are creating a new account, you must generate a new, unique ID and add that to both the map and the account.
3. Based on the above two points, your `credit()` and `debit()` functions or the ones calling them must get a hold of each account's ID and the `accounts` map and check whether it exists before doing anything else.
4. If account is not found, it is up to you to decide how you want to handle error reporting. Perhaps you could return an error code, or throw an exception, or terminate the program.